# Linux usleep: command not found, Why?

Tags: linux

When I was tring to restart dovecot service, it returns:

```
Stopping Dovecot Imap: /etc/init.d/functions: line 274: usleep: command not found
```

PS. I'm using centOS 5.2

Still have this problem， Please help.

Comment: *Does* the command actually exist?

Comment: Next time when a command is missing run `yum provides '*bin/command'` to see what package provides it and then install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Tcampbell already wrote](https://serverfault.com/a/140341/266901) it should be in `initscripts`.

You can type

```
ls -al /bin/usleep
rpm -qV initscripts
```

to see if something happened  with your `usleep`.

If it's not there I would suspect that there is a serious disk error or the machine has been broken into.

Comment: ls: /bin/usleep: No such file or directory

missing     /bin/usleep
..5....T  c /etc/inittab
S.5....T  c /etc/rc.d/rc.local

Comment: yup, looks like someone or something manually removed your /bin/usleep you can fix it by reinstalling (yum reinstall initscripts) but before that you should investigate how and why that happened

Comment: you can also run rpm -qaV and go through the output to see if anything else is missing or suspiciously changed

Answer (score 2):

What distribution?  On my RHEL 5 system, usleep is part of the initscripts RPM.